# Specifications e Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

Olá, alguém sabe alguma extensão do `dapper` que possibilite usar `Specifications (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)` em c#?

Comment: Testou dapper extensions? https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/Predicates

Comment: Tentei, ele não aceita retorno boleano de uma Expression. Da forma com que ele utiliza o Predicates.Field ele espera uma Expression com retorno de object e enums de operadores e o valor esperado.

Comment: Hm, talvez se tu colocasse teu código, tua classe e o teste que tu fez com o extensions, ficasse melhor pra ver..